# How to apply a border image troughout box-sizing on a image that dynamically changes it's size according to parent's size

Tags: html, css, border-box

Dear stackoverflow users,

I have a div which contains an image (generated by php in wordpress). This image will be 100% width and auto height according to the parents div size.

I want to apply a border image which overlays the top and bottom of this image. This can be done with box-sizing: border-box. So I did.

But for some reason the border does not overlay the image, and the image gets reduced in height size or the parent increases its height size.

I'm stuck on this for ages. Is there anyway this can be done with only css?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SE3Na/

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">
<div class="box2">
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/oj8fdc5nb/example_image.png"/>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1{
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:auto;
border:1px solid grey;}

.box2{
width:100%;
height:auto;}

.box2 img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
border-image:url(http://s30.postimg.org/atduh061p/border_banner_3.png) 12 12 12 12 repeat;
-webkit-border-image:url("http://s30.postimg.org/atduh061p/border_banner_3.png") 12 12 12 12 repeat;
-moz-border-image:url("http://s30.postimg.org/atduh061p/border_banner_3.png") 12 12 12 12 repeat;   
border-width: 12px 0px 12px 0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find :before and :after to be useful for this kind of endeavor:

```
.box1:before,
.box1:after
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.box1:after
{
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

See it in action at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SE3Na/2/)

Comment: Thank you, I was inexperienced with the before and after elements. I took your piece of code as a basis and slightly adjusted it in the way i wanted it to work.

I wanted the image to be spread 100% according to its parent (box1). So I added this. 

Then i added the box-sizing instead of the background-image. This gave me some trouble, it compressed the border image and repeated it in this compression. I fixed this by an height of 110% and an overflow:hidden. Not the most beautiful way but it does the trick.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SE3Na/3/